# Sending Email confirmation after in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have a created a time capture view in MVC project. when ever the fields are filled and submit is clicked, it should send an email confirmation of the screen with the data filled or the summary of the data to the user's email address. How can i do it?

Comment: Can you clarify if you want to just send an email of the data captured via the form?

Comment: yes. when the submit is clicked, the user should receive an email of the data captured via the form. what should i do for it?

Answer (score 0):

The question is really too broad, and there are a number of ways for you to implement this, however since this is more asking for recommendation than solving a problem I will link you to two resources.

1. [MVCMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide) - Enables you to use Views as emails, easy to use and setup
2. [SMTPClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) (Standard .NET) - Create a MailMessage and send it

In addition if you want to test to an external email service, can I recommend you [MailTrap.io](http://mailtrap.io/) - Let's you setup an inbox to test sending emails too as well as providing the SMTP Server details! Nice and easy to use

If you want any more assistance please feel free to ask, however I don't feel I can help anymore given the openness of your question